# Beamer - Combining justification and centering

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, ragged2e

I am preparing a `beamer` presentation and I am having problems in combining justification and centering. I use mainly `itemize` and `enumerate` in my slides, and I want to have the text justified in all my slides, thus I have renewed the command `\item`. Now, I need to add a table (`tabular`) in my slide (the same applies also to figures) and I want it to be centered. The standard environment `center` does not work and thus I need to use something like `\centering` to obtain the result I am looking for. This however is quite annoying, since in a set of slides I might have many tables (and figures). Is there any way to fix this centering issue automatically from the preamble?

My code follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
\oldmacro\hfill%
\insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}
\let\olditem=\item%
\renewcommand{\item}{\olditem \justifying}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketag@@@}[1]{\hbox{\m@th\normalsize\normalfont#1}}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{Bla bla bla}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item bla bla bla
\begin{center}
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
   \hline
   1 & 2 \\
   \hline
   a & b \\
   c & d \\
   \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The following is what I am trying to obtain without having to insert all the time the `\centering` command:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of [`ragged2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e)'s `\justifying` is the cause of the problem. One could just add `\centering` to the start of the `center` environment via the following preamble addition:

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\center\centering
\makeatother
```